# if statement for buttons in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, if-statement

I am coding a program which its home has 6 buttons
if you press a button, it shows a TableView when a row is pressed, it shows new viewconroller which show Row Data Details

the TableView takes its data from JSON URL and this JSON URL has all data on it (6 section).

button(X) to show Section(X)Data
[X=1; X=<6]

i coded it with a long way: every button(X) leads to [Button(X)ViewContoller] and every has [Button(X)TableViewCell]

[X=1; X=<6]

so i have 6 ViewContoller and 6 TableViewCell file.

---

i think about make an If statement for the 6 buttons instead of separated 2 file for every button, so that what i mean:

if button(X) is pressed,it will show Section(X)Data in the TableView

[[X=1; X=<6]]

i tried to do it a lot, but no way

can any one help me on If statement coding?

Comment: It looks like from your image that you should only have one table view controller with one type of cell. Your buttons could just determine which set of data you show in that one controller.

Comment: yes, that exactly what i want to do, but how can i make if for buttons

Comment: If the user clicks the first button, for example what would you like to happen?

Comment: this button will show another ViewController Scene(1) having TableView shows data that i get by section_id[] from json file
when i press one of this table rows, it show the same Scene(1) data but with more details
and every scene has a back button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to:

- Set different `tag`s for the buttons
- "Plug" all the buttons in the same method
- Check which button was clicked and change set your model accordingly

**Tip**: You can access properties of your destination view controller using the `segue.destinationViewController` property inside the `prepareForSegue(segue: sender:)` method.

---

**EDIT:** For example:

- Create `var buttonTag : Int?`
- Create a method like

  ```
  @IBAction func clicked(sender: UIButton) {
      self.buttonTag = sender.tag
  }
  ```
- Pass it on the way you think is better

  ```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      segue.destinationViewController?.buttonTag = self.buttonTag
  }
  ```
- Do whatever you have to do with data in your destination view controller

Comment: Great Tip!
now, i understood the way but it will be great if you explain with some codes,
Thank you

Comment: Great! :D if the answer helped can you please mark it as right (click the check button below on the left side of it)?